# ball on surface animation on simulink

Tags: animation, simulink

i found a example from %AHMADREZA ESHGHINEJAD () of a bouncing ball on a sinusoidal surface and tried to modify it to fit my model.

but matlab shows an error while calling the "graphicfunction" without any further information. i've been trying to figure out for hours trying to fix it, but it still does not work.

i would really appreciate your help.

main

```
   %This set of files including (Rmain.m, RCalc.m, RGraficfunction.m and Rod.mdl)  are written by:
   %AHMADREZA ESHGHINEJAD (ahmadreza.eshghinejad@gmail.com), April 2011
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % to simulate and animation of a rod falling on a flat surface.
   %
%clear
%clc
%global dblcart1 pa dt amp freq I m floormin floorwidth s R
spacing_width=0.001; %[m]
spacing_amplitude=0.008; %[m] 
%disc diameter
d=0.01; %[m]
r=d/2;  %Radius
x0=0; %% initial x
y0=spacing_amplitude; %% initial y
Bth0=0; %% initial angular position 
pa=.001;  %% pause in simulation step
T=30;  %% simulation time
m=1; %% ball mass
dt=.01;  % time steps
s=0; % Movement of frame counter 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 animinit('disc on surface');
 dblcart1 = findobj('Type','figure','Name','dblcart1 Animation');
 hold on;
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Initializing
 % Initial Ball points
 th=0:.1:2*pi;
 xx=r*cos(th)+x0;
 yy=r*sin(th)+y0;
 % Initial Ball line points
 x1l1=1*r*cos(Bth0)+x0;
 x1l2=1*r*cos(Bth0+pi)+x0;
 y1l1=1*r*sin(Bth0)+y0;
 y1l2=1*r*sin(Bth0+pi)+y0;
 x2l1=1*r*cos(Bth0+pi/2)+x0;
 x2l2=1*r*cos(Bth0+pi+pi/2)+x0;
 y2l1=1*r*sin(Bth0+pi/2)+y0;
 y2l2=1*r*sin(Bth0+pi+pi/2)+y0;
 % Drawing the floor
 floormin=0;
 floorwidth=3*2*pi*spacing_width;
 floorheight=floorwidth;
 axis([floormin floormin+floorwidth 0 floorheight]);
 plot(floormin:.1:floormin+floorwidth,spacing_amplitude*sin((1/spacing_width)*       (floormin:.1:floormin+floorwidth))+spacing_amplitude,'yellow','LineWidth',2);
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % Initial drawing of ball
 Ballhndl1=plot([x1l1 x1l2],[y1l1 y1l2],'red');
 Ballhndl2=plot([x2l1 x2l2],[y2l1 y2l2],'red');
 Ballhndl=plot(xx,yy,'blue','EraseMode','background');
 set(gca,'UserData',[Ballhndl;Ballhndl1;Ballhndl2]);
 %set(gca,'UserData',Ballhndl);
 sim('simmod.mdl')
```

matlab function inside the simulink model

```
 function [x,y,Bth] = fcn(ures,yres)
 r=0.01; %% Ball radius
 spacing_width=0.001; %[m]
 spacing_amplitude=0.008; %[m]
 for th=2*pi:-.01:0
 x=ures+r*cos(th); %% bal points
 y=yres+r*sin(th);
 end;
 Bth=atan(2*pi*(1/spacing_width)*spacing_amplitude*cos(2*pi*(1/spacing_width)*x));
```

graphic function

```
   function GraficFunction(x,y,Bth)
   global  Ball 
   spacing_width=0.001; %[m]
   pa=.01;  %% pause in simulation step
   s=0; % Movement of frame counter 
   floormin=0;
   floorwidth=3*2*pi*spacing_width;
   pause(pa)
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
   %%%%% passing the window margins and moving the object based on the "s"
   %%%%% parameter
   if x<(floormin+s*floorwidth),s=s-1;
   elseif x>((s+1)*floorwidth),s=s+1;end
   x=x-s*floorwidth;
   set(0,'currentfigure',Ball)
   Ballhndl=get(gca,'UserData');
   %Ball Circle points
   th=0:.1:2*pi;
   x1=ures+r*cos(th);
   y1=yres+r*sin(th);  
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Ball line points     
   x1l1=1*r*cos(Bth)+x;
   x1l2=1*r*cos(Bth+pi)+x;
   y1l1=1*r*sin(Bth)+y;
   y1l2=1*r*sin(Bth+pi)+y;
   x2l1=1*r*cos(Bth+pi/2)+x;
   x2l2=1*r*cos(Bth+pi+pi/2)+x;
   y211=1*r*sin(Bth+pi/2)+y;
   y2l2=1*r*sin(Bth+pi+pi/2)+y;
   % Draw Lines
   set(Ballhndl(1),'XData',x1); 
   set(Ballhndl(1),'YData',y1);
   set(Ballhndl,'XData',x1); 
   set(Ballhndl,'YData',y1);
   set(Ballhndl(2),'XData',[x1l1 x1l2]);
   set(Ballhndl(2),'YData',[y1l1 y1l2]);
   set(Ballhndl(3),'XData',[x2l1 x2l2]);
   set(Ballhndl(3),'YData',[y2l1 y2l2]);
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   drawnow;
   end
```

Comment: Try debugging this function to find the problem.